# I can't select data using where clause when imported from excel in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, excel, codeigniter

I have try to select my data from DB after I **imported** from **Excell** into DB as below code

***Problem If I copy In_no value (isp14065556) and pass into text editor and pass back into in_no in the table my select by where will work as well. Why?***

My table of **In_no** type is **varchar(30)** and I used  **In_no** for **Where clause**.

**Issue** I can selected by where if I insert **in_no** string values by typing and I can't select by where if **In_no** string value which imported from Excel ( **in_no** content which store in Excel and was imported into **Db**).

I don't understand why because **in_no** type is **varchar(30)** and I have more experience with using **Where** clause to select data from DB a lot of times. But this one I'm really don't understand why I can't select data when its was imported from excel.

```
public function printds(){
        $segment = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('dbfinan_dupl_invoice');
        $this->db->where('in_no',$segment);//tested arary('in_no'=>$segment)
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

And in controller

```
public function printd(){

        $segment = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->data['invoice_val'] = $this->invoice_m->select_ad_val($segment);
        $this->data['print_item'] = $this->invoice_m->printds($segment);
        $this->load->view('frontend/print/print_dup',$this->data);
    }
```

[image]

Thanks too much friend for your kind

Comment: Are you getting any error? Whats the value of `$segment`?

Comment: $segment = $this->uri->segment(3); I pass it from Controler to Model

Comment: @Uchiha I don't understand when I edit In_no in DB by typing its value it will work.But it can't select if I used where clause with the in_no value which imported from Excel.
Why because it also string

Comment: `$segment = $this->uri->segment(3);` this pass nothing at all

Comment: Try using `echo $this->db->last_query();` and post that query within sql and check is it working over there

Comment: @Abdulla
 
I've edited it. And I've try to declare $segment in Model too but it not work

Comment: @Uchiha,

Now I got this one 

SELECT * FROM (`dbfinan_dupl_invoice`) WHERE `in_no` = 'isp14065556'

Comment: Is it working? Did you tried it within sql

Comment: Problem If I copy In_no value (isp14065556) and pass into text editor and pass back into in_no in the table my select by where will work as well. Why?
Not I'm trying to use sql instead using CI query

Comment: @Uchiha
it is not work

Comment: As I said if I copy in_no value and pass it into text editor and copy then pass back into DB it will work.So I concern about about in_no string value.
Should have some function to clean in_no string or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81372/discussion-between-uchiha-and-cambodia-channel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Uchiha
@Abdulla
Now I found the solution Feeling happy to much

```
'in_no' =>  strtolower(trim(preg_replace("/(\D+\d{4})0*([1-9]+\d*)/i", "$1$2\n", strtolower($data['IN_number'])))),
```

I didn't clean **in_no** But after I used **`strtolower`** and **`trim`** it work as perfect 
Thanks friend for some idear

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code

```
    $segment = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['invoice_val'] = $this->invoice_m->select_ad_val($segment);
    $data['print_item'] = $this->invoice_m->printds($segment);
    $this->load->view('frontend/print/print_dup',$this->data);
```

Comment: The same as before.

I'm concern about the in_no string in my rows inside DB you know if I edited in_no content to a new string it will work.

So This case it from In_no type or sql string problem?

Comment: Problem If I copy In_no value (isp14065556) and pass into text editor and copy it then pass back into in_no in the table my select by where will work as well. Why?